# How to query only the desired period of csv file data in spark sql?

Tags: python, sql, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
from pyspark.sql import *

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName(" example")
    .config("spark.some.config.option")
    .getOrCreate()
)

df = spark.read.csv("../data/first/*.csv", inferSchema=False, header=False)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("iris")

result = spark.sql("select _c0,_c1,_c2,_c20 from iris where _c1 =1 order by _c0 ")
result.show()
```

my result

```
+-------------------+---+----------+----+
|               _c0 |_c1|       _c2|_c20|
+-------------------+---+----------+----+
|2021-01-31 00:00:00|  1|1436509798|  40|
|2021-01-31 00:00:01|  1|1436509841|  40|
|2021-01-31 00:00:02|  1|1436509886|  40|
|2021-01-31 00:00:03|  1|1436509931|  40|
,,,,
```

_c0 data is csv time data,
from 2021-01-31 00:00:00 to 2021-07-30 00:00:00
This is too much data,
So i'm trying to get from 2021-01-31 00:00:00 to 2021-02-28 23:59:59

But I don't know how to get between value in spark sql

Comment: from the official doc : [between](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.between) #ctrlF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not infering the schema, so I guess all your columns are strings.
Then, you probably just have to do this :

```py
df = df.where(df["_c0"].between("2021-01-31","2021-02-29"))
```

Comment: Thanks for kindly letting me know! 
good luck to you